# Webstorm: Adding jQuery via Libraries but can't add a reference in html

Tags: jquery, webstorm

I added jQuery to my web project in Webstorm and sure enough I see the jQuery2-0 under external libraries, but where do I add a reference to it?

I tried using code completing in the html file for my script tags, but where is it stored? In which directory?

So in the src of these script tags where do I point it?

```
<script src=""></script>
```

Webstorm seems to have downloaded the script but I am confused about how to link to it in my html file.

Answer (score 3):

When you download a library using Download... button in Settings/JavaScript/Libraries, it's not placed in your project directory - it's saved to idea.system.path/extLibs folder (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108 for information about IDE configuration/caches location; normally the idea.system.path is `~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>/system` on Windows/Linux and `~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>` on Mac).

You can copy the file (normally smth like 'http_code.jquery.com_jquery-2.0.0.js ') to your project directory and then use completion within 'src' attribute in your HTML to create a link to it, or (even better) use CDN references instead - like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I am confused. It seems a whole lot of work to download it to some hidden directory where once down i need to copy it into my projects folder. Wouldn't be downloading it manually be better.. What advantages does it give me. Thanks again!

Comment: this is actually a question what libraries are used for:) In short: downloading a library allows you to get the completion for library types without clattering your project with third-party files. By default, completion works for all js files located under your project root. So, if you do already have the library .js files in your project, it's enough to get the completion. If they are missing, and you don't like to have them in your project (as you prefer using CDN links to reference these resources), you can store them externally and add them as libraries to make them available to WebStorm.

Comment: Note also that libraries are 'light-weight' as compared with .js files in your project - they are treated read-only, have the inspections and error highlighting turned off. Plus, you can assign documentation URLs to them, enabling external documentation for library code. So, even if you have your library files in your project, it might make sense to add them as libraries

Answer (score 0):

Make a **symbolic link** from your actual directory inside your project to the external library where the JQuery file is located, using the terminal in a UNIX(-like) system:
`ln -s /Users/<USER>/Library/Caches/WebIde80/extLibs/http_code.jquery.com_jquery-<VERSION>.js jquery.js` (Mac).

Windows user might do this as well by pressing the right mousebutton selecting 'Create Alias' somewhere inside the Library directory of jQuery and move this Alias to your actual directory of your project using Explorer or using **mklink** at the MS-Command Line Tool (Powershell, ..) regarding the *idea.system.path* structure *lena* already described above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just ended up using the same src as in CodePen. src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"
I downloaded jQuery but finding the correct address was... annoying. this is an easy fix.